# pdfCropMargins: Cropping white space from a PDF

Tags: python, pdf, crop, removing-whitespace

Has anyone used pdfcropMargin? I put together a code that takes all my excel tabs and puts the tables in seperate pdf files. The next step I wanted to do was automatically crop out the whitespace. I was able to use `os.system('pdf-crop-margins sample.pdf -o output.pdf -p 0')`  where the sample pdf was all the tables in one pdf and the output was all the pdf's cropped but in one pdf. I wanted to do each pdf file individually.

```
    import win32com.client
    import pandas as pd
    from pdfCropMargins import crop
    
    
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\Documents\test\combined.xlsx')
    o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    sheets = xl.sheet_names
    
    o.Visible = False
    
    wb_path = r'C:\Users\Documents\test\combined.xlsx'
    
    wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
    
    ws_index_list = sheets #say you want to print these sheets
    
    path_to_pdf = r'C:\Users\Documents\pdftest'
    
    print_area = 'A1:I14'
    
    for index in ws_index_list:
    
        #off-by-one so the user can start numbering the worksheets at 1
        
        ws = wb.Worksheets[index]
    
        ws.PageSetup.Zoom = False
    
        ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
    
        ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = print_area
        
        
        wb.WorkSheets(index).Select()
        
        wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, (path_to_pdf+"\\"+index+'.pdf'))
        print(index)
        
        crop(['C:\\Users\\Documents\\pdftest\\'+index+'.pdf'])
```

When I run this code, I am able to successfully convert the excel tables to their seperate pdf's but when it get to the crop part I get an error that reads.

```
Warning: Document catalog data caused a write failure.  A retry
without that data succeeded.  No document catalog information was
copied to the cropped output file.  Try fixing the PDF file.  If
you have ghostscript installed, run pdfCropMargins with the '--gsFix'
option.  You can also try blacklisting some of the document catalog
items using the '--dcb' option.

Write failure, trying one more time...
```

Im not sure what's going wrong.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that the cropped file was being save a folder back. Currently it is saving the uncropped pdf's in `C:\Users\Documents\pdftest`folder but then the cropped is being saved in `C:\Users\Documents` so it goes back one folder to save it. Also it still leaves white space at the bottom of the pdf but removes the whitespace from the top and sides.